# Rename Files having EmDash using a Batch File

Tags: batch-file, special-characters

I have a ton of files containing em dashes within the file name. 
I am having trouble renaming them, as cmd apparently fails to recognize it, and converts emdash into a regular dash. 
As a result I get the following error after I run the `ren` command:

```
ren "MyFile With – EmDash.txt" "MyFile.txt"   
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Things I have tried

1. **Inserting `chcp 65001` at start of batch code.**

   This command does not seem to work.
2. **Saving the batch file as ANSI in Notepad**

What this does is basically the following:

```bat
ren "MyFile With û EmDash.txt" "MyFile.txt"
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

As one can guess apparently saving `ANSI` format changes a character stored as em dash in notepad to `û` when batch file runs in a cmd window.

I have got dozens of files which need this renaming, and this would be monotonous to do so without a batch script.

Comment: _Saving the batch file as ANSI in Notepad_. Then, insert `CHCP 1252` (or whatever your _ANSI_ means: should work for 1252, 1250, 1257, 1253, 1251, 1254, 874, 1255, 1256, 1258 AFAIK).

Comment: @JosefZ Thanks. That fixed. What exactly is the logic behind this ? I understand that CMD by default does not have a dictionary for certain special characters. But is there a reason why 1252 code was specifically used ? Thanks again.

Comment: `1252` is the [Windows code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page) intended for Western European Latin and is the most widely used, making it a good place to start.

Comment: `reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage" | findstr "CP.*_SZ"` shows current _ANSI_, _OEM_ and _MAC_ code pages. One should save and run a batch file in the same  code page…